# Entity Spaces networking error

Tags: entity

I have a site that I am trying to deploy, until recently it would work in development but now I am getting the error:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.

This is without changing the code, just simply trying to publish it for the most part.

I realize this isn't much to go on, here is my connection string:

```
 <add name="SQL" providerMetadataKey="esDefault" sqlAccessType="DynamicSQL" provider="EntitySpaces.SqlClientProvider" providerClass="DataProvider" connectionString="User ID=FDDUSER;Password=notreallyit; Initial Catalog=FDD; Data Source=FDD_Alias" databaseVersion="2008" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out my problem was with the alias.  I'm not sure why, but changing that fixed it.